# Usage of Future tense will and to be + ing-form

Tags: tenses, future

Could anyone please explain the usage of the future tense 'will' and 'to be +ing-form'? Is it correct to say 'I will clean the kitchen right now.' (I am about to do something in the very near future) and 'I am working tomorrow.' (my intention)
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There is no future tense in English. We refer to the future using practically any tense, and _will_ is not required. The progressive construction _be V-ing_ is also used. So is the present (_I leave tomorrow_) and many other constructions (_I am to leave tomorrow, I'm going to leave tomorrow, I expect to leave tomorrow, I'm supposed to leave tomorrow,_ etc. There is no meaning difference, and one may use whichever form one pleases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure can say *"I will clean the kitchen right now."* It sounds like a **decision made at the moment of speaking**. In other words, you didn't plan cleaning, but then you looked around and understood you couldn't put it off any longer, and said, *"OK, I'll clean right now."*

We use the Present Continuous to talk about the future if there are some **arrangements** (often with *tonight*, *at 9*, *this weekend*, etc.). So, if it's an arrangement, you can say "I'm working tomorrow." However, *"I'm going to work tomorrow"* may be better as long as you mean your **intention**.

Compare the Present Continuous (for arrangements) and *to be going to do something* (for intentions):

> I'm having my hair cut today. I'm seeing my dentist tomorrow. I'm meeting Mike on Saturday. (I've made arrangements)
>
> I'm going to get a job that earns me a lot of money. I'm not going to leave the house at all on Wednesday. (These are my plans)